# Spring-boot and MS SQL Server in docker compose: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I created a docker compose file to run a spring-boot application (2.5.7) and a MS SQL Server:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    ports:
      - 1434:1433
    build: ./db
  api:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build: ./mdm-web-api
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - $SPRING_LOCAL_PORT:$SPRING_DOCKER_PORT
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://db:1434;databaseName=dwh-demo;encrypt=true;logingTimeout=30
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

I defined a Dockerfile for the mssql in the folder 'db' and successfully tested the SQL server alone.

I added my spring-boot application, which I also tested separately.

I have an application.properties file as follow (I replace sensible values):

```
logging.level.root=INFO
spring.datasource.username=<my-db-user>
spring.datasource.password=<my-ultra-strong-pw>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema:entity_reference
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
```

I just added the spring.datasource.url properties in the **docker-compose.yml** to be able to point to the database server using the service name:

```
environment:
          - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:sqlserver://db:1434;databaseName=dwh-demo;encrypt=true;logingTimeout=30
```

It seems like the SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL value is completely ignored and I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to determine suitable jdbc url

It shouldn't be a problem to use both places to add configuration, but maybe I'm wrong.

What could be the problem and which alternative do I have?

Additional details:
java openjdk 19
maven 3.8.5
Docker on Windows
SQL Server 2019-latest for Linux

Comment: Do you need to specify the port in your url?

Comment: If the standard database port is 1433, you need to use that port number in `$SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`.  Connections between containers don't use `ports:` and ignore them if they happen to be present.

Comment: I left the standard port for the internal network and used the 1434 for external. I now realized I need to change it to 1433 or get rid of it between the two containers.

Comment: If you decide to use a custom port again in the future I'd recommend against 1434. tcp/1434 is for the Dedicated Admin Connection on SQL Server and would only cause confusion for the people that are aware of it (it only allows a single active connection and then only for a sysadmin role member).

Comment: I'm still having the same problem, it is not port related, it seems like the `$SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` in the docker-compose.yml is just ignored. This is the error summary: APPLICATION FAILED TO START - Description: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. Reason: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url

Comment: I just added all the required config. to the `application.properties` file, my concern was regarding the server name, since it is not localhost any longer. It seems like the service name used in `docker-compose.yml`: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://db:1433;databaseName=dwh-demo;encrypt=true;logingTimeout=30` It still fails but I think the problem relies in the API not waiting for the DB to be ready. I'm testing the health check and conditions.